# Sqlite3 returning empty array with GET request in Express

Tags: express, node-sqlite3

I am trying to make a get request to an sqlite3 table, using Express, based on input from a form. The fetch request works and so does the db.all, but I receive a response as an empty array from rows. I tried req.query and req.params already. Not sure where the error is.

//server.js

```
app.get('/names/state', (req, res, next) => {
    const stateValue = req.query.state;
    db.all(`SELECT name FROM states WHERE name=$stateVal`, 
        {
            $stateVal: stateValue
        },
    (err, rows) => {
            res.send({rows:rows});  
    })
});
```

//script.js

```
const fetchOneBtn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const stateVal = stateInputValue.value;

    fetch(`/names/state?state=${stateVal}`)
    .then(response =>{
        if(response.ok){

            return response.json();
        }
    }).then(names => {
        console.log(names);
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code in your backend with this code below:

```js
app.get('/names/state', (req, res, next) => {
  const stateValue = req.query.state;
  var query = "SELECT name FROM states WHERE name = " + stateValue;

  db.all(query, (err, rows) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }else {
      res.send({rows});  
    }
  })
});
```

Now, for your frontend, you can change with the code below:

```js
const fetchOneBtn = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const stateVal = stateInputValue.value;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`/names/state?state=${stateVal}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    });
    console.log(await response.json());
    return await response.json();
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex);
  }
};
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Gives a 500 error and cites  const response = await fetch(`/names/state?state=${stateVal}`);

Comment: Not an empty array but {"errno":1,"code":"SQLITE_ERROR"}

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm typo. I've been update my select query. You can try it.

Comment: First, you can console.log(rows) in your server.js and try again. See, what the result in your console.

Comment: The error is being thrown even before the request can be made

Comment: From my code above, you can comment first, everything in try catch block and try again. Let's to see, you get some error or not. If you still get some error, then your problem is not sqlite3. **Don't forget to console.log(stateVal)**

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm forget to add method. You can see my updated code in frontend.

Comment: Same issue. console.log(stateVal) produces the value from my form's input.

Comment: I changed my original code, I reduced the routes ('/names) but now I receive all my rows, as opposed to just one row.

Comment: If you want to only one array, than you can set your response like as this: `res.send({rows: rows[0]});  `

Comment: I'm trying to grab one array, but based on the query input in the form. I have a list of 52 US states. I want to grab the one typed in within the input field.

Comment: I think in the query above, there's where clause. But if you have data where's the name same with your input, then it's will show all of them

Comment: I think it may be an issue with my routes. I have another get request app.get('/names). It gets all the arrays. I tried app.get('/names/state?state=${stateVal}), I get an empty array. I commented out the app.get('/names) and used it for the query request. Even with res.send({rows: rows[0]}] I still get 52 arrays.

Comment: Why you're use `stateval`? because your variable is `stateValue`, not `stateVal`.

Comment: Good catch! I changed those typos. and now I am back at an empty array.

Comment: Maybe it is right, no value with those name filter. Hahaha